# How to get table row values in a javascript function from a dynamically created table using for loop in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

So basically, I am passing a context from views to my template.

In my template I am using 'for loop' to view the context in a tabular form and also attaching a button for every table row.

When that button is clicked, I want to call a javascript function(that has ajax call).
I need to get values of row elements for that particular row to use in my function.

My view function:

```
def asset_delivery(request):
  deliverylist = Delivery.objects.filter(status='Added to Delivery List')
  context = {'deliverylist': deliverylist}
  return render(request, 'gecia_ass_del.html', context)
```

So far I tried passing those values as parameters in the following way.
My html template table:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead style="background-color:DodgerBlue;color:White;">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Barcode</th>
      <th scope="col">Owner</th>
      <th scope="col">Mobile</th>
      <th scope="col">Address</th>
      <th scope="col">Asset Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Approve Asset Request</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for i in deliverylist %}
    <tr>
      <td id="barcode">{{i.barcode}}</td>
      <td id="owner">{{i.owner}}</td>
      <td id="mobile">{{i.mobile}}</td>
      <td id="address">{{i.address}}</td>
      <td id="atype">{{i.atype}}</td>
      <td><button id="approvebutton" onclick="approve({{i.barcode}},{{i.owner}},{{i.mobile}},{{i.address}},{{i.atype}})" style="background-color:#288233; color:white;" class="btn btn-indigo btn-sm m-0">Approve Request</button></td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The table is displayed perfectly but the button or the onclick or the function call does not seem to work.

My javascript function:

```
<script>
    function approve(barcode2, owner2, mobile2, address2, atype2){
        console.log('entered approved');
        var today = new Date().getFullYear()+'-'+("0"+(new Date().getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'-'+("0"+new Date().getDate()).slice(-2);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'deliveryupdate/'+barcode+'/',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{
                barcode: barcode2,
                owner: owner2,
                mobile: mobile2,
                address: address2,
                atype: atype2,
                status:'Authority Approved',
                statusdate: today,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                    console.log('before send');
                  },
            success: function(){
              console.log("success log");
              swal("Success!","Asset request has been approved","success");
            },
            error: function(){
              console.log("error");
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

I checked the browser logs and it looks like the function is not getting executed, meaning the problem lies with the function call or the button. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working on my end. I have reduced the function to:

```
function approve(){console.log('entered approved');}
```

without any parameters and 'entered approved' is logged to the console. Check if you are setting the correct parameters and if the console throws an error. Simplify your function and add the parameters one by one in order to troubleshoot this.